# beforeShowDay in bootstrap datepicker disables the next date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have mulitple datepickers on a page, once I select one I want to disable it from the next datepicker. I have used the below code.

```
jQuery('.date-picker', jForm).datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    beforeShowDay:function(Date){
        var curr_date = Date.toJSON().substring(0,10);
        if (forbidden.indexOf(curr_date)>-1) return false;        
    }
});
```

Forbidden is the array of selected dates, the above code disables the following day, not the selected one (example if I select 2015-06-04 it disables 2015-06-05).

Comment: do you want somrthing like this https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: Not a range, a single date.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or show me the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zsqvjvkd/119/

Comment: what you want to be done ,can you come with more explanation

Comment: If you click on the textbox, a datepicker appears if you see some of the dates are disabled. These dates are a day after the dates added in the forbidden array. I want the date mentioned in the array to be disabled not the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am not using bootstrap datepicker

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/8tjf8nv0/)**

```
var unavailableDates = ["19-8-2015","14-8-2015"];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
    } else {
        return [false,"","Booked Out"];
    }
}

$('#unvailable').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```